# How do you reset a button from "clicked" to "unclicked"

Tags: javascript, button, reset, click

I have tried things like the following, but to no avail. (I am a novice programmer, so be nice.)

```
document.getElementById('Button1').clicked = false;
document.getElementById('Button1').value = false;
document.getElementById('Button1').value = document.getElementById('Button1').defaultValue;
```

Comment: What does `clicked` denote?

Comment: Click is an event, not a state. You cannot switch it on and off. You can listen for the event and do something.

Comment: This question is about buttons, not selects, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Normal buttons do not behave this way. Links do, but not buttons. I'm thinking anything that has an ID of 'Button1' in Your page is actually a link `<a href="" id="Button1">Some Text</a>`, that has a CSS style (or none at all) making it appear differently once You clicked it at least once, am i right?

If so, You don't need javascript for now. You should create (or edit an existing) CSS sheet, and style your "Button1" in it. How to do it? [Read here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)

Comment: My button is as follows: <button name="Button1" id="Button1"> Button </button>. But if what @SebastianG said is correct, then the button must not hold a value that switches between clicked/unclicked.

Comment: Yes, if you click a button it will do something and will return on its own. At this point i don't understand what are you trying to achieve. Tell me what exactly is wrong with your page, what happens when you click this button and what do you want to happen?

Comment: I'm actually debugging some code I wrote and thought the issue was the button because when I don't click it the code runs fine. However now I think it must be one of the functions the button queues to run. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to do this, you could use CSS `visited` property to show if the link is clicked